# How do I rebuild the training demo sites?

Tags: civicrm-buildkit

After ssh'ing in:
$ ssh joemurray@www-training.civicrm.osuosl.org
I was going to restore the first 3 of 25 training sites using:

civibuild restore PARM_SITES="01 02 03"

as per the documentation for buildkit at  https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/doc/civibuild.md#rebuilds and a tip from Tim about the parameter.

However, the civibuild command wasn't available in my path and I couldn't find the file either. I was expecting it to be available on this server. Has it been renamed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demo sites are built as a [scheduled job in Jenkins](https://test.civicrm.org/view/Sites/). Authenticated users in Jenkins can start builds from the gui. Please contact the core team via email (totten or dave or coleman or kurund, at civicrm.org) if you need a login to that site.

Comment: Thanks, Coleman. Does Mathieu (mlufty at bidon.ca) also have the authority to create accounts or reset passwords.